# My Team's accounts

Tags: account, account-teams

We are right now moving all Accounts in our org under one user 1.e, there will just be one unique Account owner for all accounts and all those sales executives who want to work on an account will have to add themselves to the Account Team. How can the manager now see the list of accounts in which his team is working with?

Comment: To answer this well, I need a bit more info. Are your users in different roles in the Role Hierarchy? Do all managers have 1 team reporting to them? One thing I worry about is you having an ownership skew, can you explain the situation and why the design change?